# Bluetooth hardware info

Tags: bluetooth

Using Android, is there a way to know which is the hardware manufacture and more details about the Bluetooth hardware of the device I'm using?
I have different behavior of my Bluetooth app using different device (smartphone LG and Sony tablet) and I'd like to get inside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Android BT stack is based on bluez.  You can use hciconfig to interact with the hardware device and get info about exact capabilities and manufacturer.  Here's a link describing this: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/projects/bluetooth-faq

Comment: I can't use hciconfig 'cause I've not root access.

Comment: Android changed to BlueDroid recently.. Please help to spread the word and star a bug in BlueDroid so we attract more attention and it got fixed as soon as possible here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66177&thanks=66177&ts=1392831163